# Service Fabric - Service initialization failed

Tags: c#, service-fabric-stateful, azure-service-fabric

I'm using visual studio 2015 and I have created a default Statefull project and having this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Fabric.FabricException' in mscorlib.dll An
>   unhandled exception of type 'System.Fabric.FabricException' occurred
>   in SPMService.exe System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Exception HRESULT: 0x80071D2D

I have not changed App.config or package.config (it's a default project).

```
<packages>
<package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric" version="6.1.456" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data" version="3.0.456" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnostics.Internal" version="3.0.456" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services" version="3.0.456" targetFramework="net452" /> </packages>
```

**In my Default Statefull project (which  has made to test the error) i have the error ever 14 sec more or less.**

> *11:21:14.561    ServiceHostInizializationFailed    Service host inizializzation failed.

It counts till 14 the i have the error Service host initialization failed:

[image: 14 sec error] 
Screen error of every 14 sec more or less

[image: LOG]
The full log of the error

[image: Main project error]
Error in my main project which is the same as my default test project Statefull

[image: Versions] Versions information of my packages

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the version of the Service Fabric Tools installed on your machine matches the Nuget packages you reference in code. Ideally they should be the same.
Use the web platform installer to install the latest tools. `3.0.456 (VS2015)`

Higher versions of Nuget packages are not always compatible with lower versions of the SDK.
Use Nuget package manager to install the latest packages. `3.0.456`

Comment: I added on my main post the screen about the versions of my packages, and they seems to be the same version as ur suggestion.

If u can try to be as much clear as u can while im new in .NET and with ServiceFabric, Tnx for helping me.

Comment: First install Web Platform Installer, http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255386 Next, run it to install `Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools 3.0.456 (VS2015)`

Comment: I installed from the Web Platform 5.0 and if i run the file you linked me it says "Installed".
You can see it from the last screen of my post i just added a new screen that shows you the versions of my packages and the Web Platform from where i installed Service fabrick SDK and Tools

Comment: Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK - 3.0.456  Installed
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools - 3.0.456(VS2015)  Installed
Microsoft Azure PowerShell  Installed

Comment: do you have sufficient disk space?

Comment: 335 GB Avalaible on "C:", the only partition i have.

Comment: Forgot to tell you that i tryed to use many version of .NET (when i create a default project it uses 4.5.2) but all of them give me the same Exception

Comment: What happens if you create a new project with a stateful service, without any custom code in it, and run that? Does that work?

Comment: it doesent work, 1st, 2nd and 4rth screens are about my default Statefull project

Comment: can you run your service on a (party) cluster in Azure and see if it's your code, or local cluster? (https://try.servicefabric.azure.com/)